# combine data in depending on the value of one column

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R

```
     year group  sales
1   2000     1    20
2   2001     1    25
3   2002     1    23
4   2003     1    30
5   2001     2    50
6   2002     2    55
```

And I want to group the data by groups or create some kind of object. I want to create one array for each group that will store the year and the sales. And the I will try to save it as a json file with this structure:

```
[{"group": 1, "sales":[[2000,20],[2001, 25], [2002,23], [2003, 30]]},
{"group": 2, "sales":[[2001, 50], [2002,55]]}]
```

Is it possible to do it automatically?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table` to `paste` the 'year' and 'sales' column grouped by 'group.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Group by 'group', we use `sprintf` to paste the 'year', 'sales' along with the parentheses (`[]`), then collapse the output to a single string with `toString` (it is a wrapper for `paste(..., collapse=', ')`), `paste` the `[]`, and use `toJSON`.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)
toJSON(setDT(df1)[, list(sales= paste0('[',toString(sprintf('[%d,%d]',
                  year, sales)),']')), by = group])
#[{"group":1,"sales":"[[2000,20], [2001,25], [2002,23], [2003,30]]"},
#{"group":2,"sales":"[[2001,50], [2002,55]]"}]
```

---

The `paste` by group can be done using `base R`.  We `split` the dataset by the 'group' column to create a `list`.  Loop through the `list` with `lapply`, `paste`, the 'year', 'sales' column as mentioned above. Create a `data.frame` with the first element of 'group' and the string from the `paste` step, `rbind` the `list` elements to create a single `data.frame` and then use `toJSON`.

```
toJSON(
     do.call(rbind,
         lapply(
            split(df1, df1$group),
                function(x) data.frame(group=x$group[1L], 
                           sales=paste0('[',
                            toString(sprintf('[%d,%d]', x$year, x$sales)),
              ']')))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2001L, 2002L
 ), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), sales = c(20L, 25L, 23L, 
30L, 50L, 55L)), .Names = c("year", "group", "sales"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: You don't need to convert 'data.frame' to 'data.table'.

Comment: @vck I used `data.table` only for doing the `paste` by group. I can do the same steps in `base R`, but I thought using `data.table` would be easier for the paste part

Comment: I run your code without `setDT`, and it produce same output.

Comment: @vck You must have run it once.  So the 'data.frame' would be converted to 'data.table'.  In subsequent runs the call is not needed.  Just try by copy/pasting the data, and run without `setDT`

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answer uses `data.table`, I thought it would be a interesting exercise to try to do this in `dplyr`.  This is not the optimal way but illustrates `do` which I'm not convinced is well enough documented.  I have also shown the more appropriate `summarise` solution.

```
df <-read.table(textConnection('
year   group sales  expenses
2000     1    20     19
2001     1    25     19
2002     1    23     20
2003     1    30     15
2001     2    50     27
2002     2    55     30
'),header=TRUE)   


library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

df %>%
  group_by( group ) %>%
  do(
     sales = group_by(.,year) %>% select(sales) %>% apply(MARGIN=2,identity),
     expenses = group_by(.,year) %>% select(expenses) %>% apply(MARGIN=2,identity)
  )

df %>%
  group_by( group ) %>%
  summarise(
    sales = list(apply( data.frame(year,sales), MARGIN=2, identity ))
    ,expenses = list(apply( data.frame(year,sales), MARGIN=2, identity ))
  ) %>% jsonlite::toJSON()
```