# create list by groups and create json

Tags: r

Ok I had this problem that has been solved

[combine data in depending on the value of one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310373/combine-data-in-depending-on-the-value-of-one-column)

I have been trying to adapt the solution for a more complicated problem but i have not been able to come with the solution instead of 2 columns i have 3

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2001L, 2002L), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), sales = c(20L, 25L, 23L, 30L, 50L, 55L), expenses = c(19L, 19L, 20L, 15L, 27L, 30L)), .Names = c("year", "group", "sales", "expenses"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

    year   group sales  expenses
1   2000     1    20     19
2   2001     1    25     19
3   2002     1    23     20
4   2003     1    30     15
5   2001     2    50     27
6   2002     2    55     30
```

And I need the same output as in the first problem but instead of just the sales I also need to include the expenses in the json file

```
[{"group": 1, "sales":[[2000,20],[2001, 25], [2002,23], [2003, 30]], "expenses":[[2000,19],[2001, 19], [2002,20], [2003, 15]]},
{"group": 2, "sales":[[2001, 50], [2002,55]], "expenses":[[2001, 27], [2002,30]]}]
```

Comment: could you do `deparse(your_data)` and paste it for reproducibility?

Comment: @timelyportfolio `dput()`? (or `cat(deparse())`, mebbe?)

Comment: It should be pretty clear from the previous answer how to do this - reread the answer and try and figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
toJSON(setDT(df1)[, list(sales= paste0('[',toString(sprintf('[%d,%d]',year, sales)),']'),
                     expenses= paste0('[',toString(sprintf('[%d,%d]', year, expenses)),']')), by = group])
```

Try this. Its not different than akrun's answer.[combine data in depending on the value of one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310373/combine-data-in-depending-on-the-value-of-one-column)

Comment: added a `dplyr` solution to the "replicated" question; can't add here since voted down